# Result using spring data JPA Async queries

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I've one question, I am using spring boot 1.5.9.RELEASE and spring data JPA with Hibernate.

My queries are like

```
@Async
CompletableFuture<User> findById(final long id);
```

And my question is, what result will I have if the id is not in the database?
a CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null) or null directly?

Thanks in advance !.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have a `CompletableFuture<User>` with a null inside.

As a rule of thumb, any spring data jpa async repo calls would never itself be null.